# Which method to overwrite for view inside ListView to always get correct size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Which method should I override to be guaranteed to always get the correct size of a view?
I tried onSizeChanged and onLayout but it seems to me that when views are recycled inside the listView those methods are not always called.

So is there any better way to be notified of the current view size?

Comment: so you also want the listview's count also along with root

Comment: No, I want to be notified of the size of the children of a listView, not the size of the listView itself

Comment: Why would you want to be notified of size changes of children? Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish want you want?

Comment: For my app it is necessary to request images from a server with the correct size of the Views, the usual Android approach to handle different view sizes is no option for my table cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the methods onMeasure and onLayout. These methods are called whenever something happens in layout (a focus change, a resize of an element, ecc..)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. These methods also get called when a table cell is reused.